# linphone compile issue (just downloaded from git)

Tags: ios, objective-c, git, linphone

I followed the instruction from here http://www.linphone.org/eng/download/git.html.

I open terminal and entered `git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-iphone.git --recursive`
(I included `--recursive`)

But after that I can't compile, because some files are missing:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try and repeat the command which is done the "`--recursive`" part of a [`git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) (that actually calls [`git submodule`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)):

```
cd /path/to/linphone # your main parent repo
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

And see if there are any error message, or if the missing files show up.

Comment: that didn't help, after that command I see that it's checking some files (I see it at the header of terminal window), but in the main window (where there is all the text) I don't see anything. And when the check is finished, I see only this string "linphone-iphone admin$". So I think , it means that there is no any missing files found.

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the instructions in the README file to compile the sdk first?  Linphone for iPhone depends on liblinphone sdk.

The README is quite detailed but is focused on Macports, if you want to use Homebrew have a look here:

http://www.successmonkey.co.nz/blog/building-linphone-for-ios

And for Macports a blog with some more details and some discussion:

http://shallwelearn.com/blog/build-linphone-for-iphone-and-ipad/